# TYPO3 12 LTS Fluid:: The rendering context of ViewHelper f:uri.page is missing a valid request object

Tags: typo3, typo3-12.x

In frontend of one of the controller view I'm getting this error.

```
<f:uri.page pageUid="1">Hello World</f:uri.page>
```

Thanks for your help.

[image]

In core :

update: The view was rendered using StandAloneView inside the controlled (this is a compatibility fix project and dont have about code overview before)

Answer (score 2):

I found the issue. Inside the controller I found that the view was rendered using StandAloneView and in TYPO3 12 request variable is not set anymore outside the Extbase context.

See Here: https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/12.4/en-us/Changelog/12.0/Breaking-98377-FluidStandaloneViewDoesNotCreateAnExtbaseRequestAnymore.html

So the error is fixed by setting request parameter inside the controller where the StandAloneView is initialized.

```
$view = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(StandaloneView::class);
        $view->setTemplatePathAndFilename($renderFile);
        $view->setFormat('html');
        $view->setRequest($this->request);
```